# Can't use parameters in subquery when selecting from view

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector-python

**System:** MariaDB 10.3.15, python 3.7.2, mysql.connector python package

I'm having trouble to determine to the exact cause of a problem, possibly a bug in MariaDB/mySQL, when executing the query with the table structure as described below. The confusing part is the error message

`1356 (HY000): View 'test_project.denormalized' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them`

which seems to relate to the problem at first, but the further I dig into why this is happening, the more I get the feeling this error message is a red herring.

**Steps to reproduce:**

```sql
CREATE DATABASE `test_project`;

USE `test_project`;

CREATE TABLE `normalized` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign_key` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `normalized` (`foreign_key`, `name`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'attr_1', '1'),
(1, 'attr_2', '2'),
(2, 'attr_1', '3'),
(2, 'attr_2', '4');

CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `denormalized` AS 
select
    max(`iq`.`foreign_key`) AS `foreign_key`,
    max(`iq`.`attr_1`) AS `attribute_1`,
    max(`iq`.`attr_2`) AS `attribute_2`
from (
    select
        `foreign_key` AS `foreign_key`,
        if(`name` = 'attr_1',`value`,NULL) AS `attr_1`,
        if(`name` = 'attr_2',`value`,NULL) AS `attr_2`
    from `normalized`
) as `iq`
group by `iq`.`foreign_key`;
```

Using python connect to the database and execute the following query:

```py
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="somehost", user="someuser", password="somepassword")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """select * from denormalized as d
where d.`foreign_key` in
(
    SELECT distinct(foreign_key)
    FROM normalized
    where value = %s
);"""
cursor.execute(query, ["2"])
results = cursors.fetchall()
```

**Further information:** At first I thought that obviously it's a privilege issue, but even using root for everything and double checking hosts and specific privileges didn't change anything.

Then I dug deeper into what the queries and views involved do (the test case above is a reduced version of what's actually in our database) and tested each part. Selecting from the view works. Running the query of the view works. Selecting from the view with a static subquery works. In fact, replacing the view in the problematic query with it's definition works too.

I've boiled it down to selecting from the view using a subquery in the `where` clause using parameters in that subquery. This causes the error to appear. Using a static subquery or replacing the view with it's definition works just fine, it's only this specific circumstance where it fails.

And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group by does not make sense; did you really mean one of these?

This returns one row:

```
select  max(`foreign_key`) AS `foreign_key`,
        max(if(`name` = 'attr_1', `value`,NULL)) AS `attribute_1`,
        max(if(`name` = 'attr_2', `value`,NULL)) AS `attribute_2`
    from  `normalized`;
```

This uses the `GROUP BY` and returns one row per `foreign_key`:

```
select  `foreign_key`,
        max(if(`name` = 'attr_1', `value`,NULL)) AS `attribute_1`,
        max(if(`name` = 'attr_2', `value`,NULL)) AS `attribute_2`
    from  `normalized` 
    group by  `foreign_key`;
```

Your python query is probably better in either of these formulations:

```
select  d.*
    FROM ( SELECT  distinct(foreign_key)
            FROM  normalized
            where
             value  = %s  )
    JOIN  denormalized as d;

select  d.*
    FROM denormalized as d
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
            FROM  normalized
            where foreign_key = d.foreign_key
              AND value  = %s  )
```

They would benefit from `INDEX(value, foreign_key)`.

Comment: The original view works as expected, but I do admit there are probably better ways to achieve the same thing. In your second query the ```group by``` is necessary because otherwise the ```max``` group over the entire table instead of each dataset grouped by ```foreign_key```. I will change the view to use this structure as the definition query. The view is intended to provide a convenient overview over attributes while the actual data should be stored in a normalized table.

Comment: What I'm trying to do with the query in the python script is a crude search. For convenience I select from the denormalized view, but want to include only rows that contain the search term in any of the attributes. Thus I'm selecting the keys from the normalized table, where selecting is easy, and use them to select from the view where the presentation is convenient. I'm still not sure why my original approach produced a seemingly unrelated error, but thanks to you answer I can work around it so I consider this problem solved. Thanks!